# I can't execute pdf generation python command form PHP

Tags: javascript, php, python, pdf

I give `python` command using `php`

```
exec("xyz.py" .query );
```

Some part of my code run and create also html file and text file 
but in some other part of my code is not running and not creating pdf from php via web browser. But when i run same python file from folder they create all three file : `.txt, html , pdf` files.

Answer (score 1):

Please try:

```
@exec("python /FULL_PATH/xyz.py".$query);
```

Comment: @opensourcepy Can you show me your terminal command or error messages?

Comment: I run this command through browser (in my web application)that will create html file and that html file will show in iframe. and that will not show any error i used " 2>&1" also  for showing an error but it will show NULL. and this is my command exec("python" . "/var/www/". $dir_name . "/time/xyz.py"  . $query );

Comment: @opensourcepy exec("python " . "/var/www/". $dir_name . "/time/xyz.py" . $query ); I found you miss a blank after "python". If i debug this code i will print the command string and run it in the terminal.

Comment: I tried this give blank after "python" but it can't resolve my problem.